# Android - How to pass a bitmap image from one activity to another activity without loosing image quality

Tags: java, android

I want to import an image from my mobile gallery using Button in Activity1 and display it in Activity2.

I'm using the following code to do so:

In MainAcitivity:

```
 public void pickImageFromGallery(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("scale", false);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_PHOTO);
    }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_PHOTO) {
            final Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                //Get image
                Bitmap myPic = extras.getParcelable("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                myPic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

In MainActivity2:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImage);
        byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

I'm Importing high-quality image but getting very low Image Quality in ImageView. Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: On most devices, you will not get anything. `ACTION_PICK` does not take extras, and it does not return a value in a `data` extra.

Comment: Don't use a compression algorithm which reduces quality -> `myPic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);`